# sql simple update statement doesn't work

Tags: c#, sql, sql-update

The update  simply doesn't work, **the row stays the same** .I get no error.Does anyone know the reason why it doesn't work ? 
I'd like to know firstly the cause of the problem but if you have any ideas, suggestions about how to improve my code, they we'll  be welcomed.

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=E:\C #\InsertDeleteUpdate-Login\InsertDeleteUpdate-Login\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True"))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE info SET Password=@Password WHERE Id=@Id AND Password=@Password1",conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", textBox4.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", textBox3.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password1", textBox2.Text);
        }
    }
```

Comment: you need to execute the query

Comment: use: `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`

Comment: you are missing `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`

Comment: @SonerGönül , it is a prototype, all i want is to learn.

Comment: And do not use `AddWithValue` method. Use `Add` method to specify your parameter type and it's size. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: This answer to another question from you has the answer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31791708/simple-ordinary-sql-server-insert-method  And why have you not accepted any answers?

Comment: i forgot, i accepted one now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to execute the query

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", textBox4.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", textBox3.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password1", textBox2.Text);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // this is what was missing
```

Comment: thx a lot, you know, in this app i had another query where i SELECT something  and that statement works without executenonquery, that's why i believed it is not needed here too.

Comment: A Select is executed implicitly while UPDATE and DELETE require an explicit execution statement.

Answer (score 3):

You are not executing the query.  You need to use:

```
cmd.ExcecuteNonQuery();
```

after adding the parameters.

Answer (score 2):

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=E:\C #\InsertDeleteUpdate-Login\InsertDeleteUpdate-Login\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True"))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE info SET Password=@Password WHERE Id=@Id AND Password=@Password1",conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", textBox4.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", textBox3.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password1", textBox2.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need `conn.close()` part. `using` statement handle that.