# Insert data into a table in database C#

Tags: c#

I intend to populate an access DB table that has three columns; Entity(text type), Date and Value(double type). 
I wrote the following code by going through some online links. Although the code runs fine, the table has no data. I am probably missing some part. Any advice?

```
for (int i = 0; i < model.CDFResults.Count; i++)
{ // connection details to the DB here...
    for (int j = 0; j < model.CDFResults[i].DataPoints.Count; j++)
    {
        OleDbCommand myAccessCommand = new OleDbCommand();
        myAccessCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        myAccessCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TypeCurves([Entity],[Date],[Value])VALUES(?,?,?)";
        myAccessCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Entity", model.CDFResults[i].catname_db);
        myAccessCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", model.CDFResults[i].DataPoints[j].dt);
        myAccessCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", model.CDFResults[i].DataPoints[j].CDFVal);


    } // end of FOR(j) loop

} // end of FOR(i) loop
```

EDIT: Still not working

```
for (int i = 0; i < model.CDFResults.Count; i++)
{ // connection details to the DB here...
    for (int j = 0; j < model.CDFResults[i].DataPoints.Count; j++)
    {

        OleDbConnection thisConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionname);
        thisConnection.Open();

        OleDbCommand myAccessCommand = new OleDbCommand();
        myAccessCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        myAccessCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TypeCurves([Entity],[Date],[Value])VALUES(?,?,?)";
        myAccessCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Entity", model.CDFResults[i].catname_db);
        myAccessCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", model.CDFResults[i].DataPoints[j].dt);
        myAccessCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", model.CDFResults[i].DataPoints[j].CDFVal);

        myAccessCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();    
    } // end of FOR(j) loop
} // end of FOR(i) loop
```

Comment: you don't seem to be executing the query

Comment: How do I do that? @user1666620

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert Data into database in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389803/insert-data-into-database-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need create the connection to the database and execute the query.

```
using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{   
    string query = "INSERT INTO TypeCurves([Entity],[Date],[Value])VALUES(@Entity,@Date,@Value)";
    OleDbCommand myAccessCommand = new OleDbCommand(query, connection);
    myAccessCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Entity", model.CDFResults[i].catname_db);
    myAccessCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", model.CDFResults[i].DataPoints[j].dt);
    myAccessCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", model.CDFResults[i].DataPoints[j].CDFVal);

    connection.Open();
    myAccessCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

`connectionString` is whatever your connection string is to your database.

In this example you don't need to explicitly close the connection after the query is executed as the connection is wrapped in a `using` block, and so will be disposed of once it has exited the block.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I added it but I get an error saying "ExecuteNonQuery:Connection property has not been initialized."

Comment: @user5752879 you need to create a connection to the database.

Comment: Thanks. I understood the concept too!

Comment: @Aron Your downvote is unwarranted. If you check the question edit history (and my answer history), I originally stated that he needed to execute the query. However then it turned out that in addition to not executing the query, the OP wasn't creating a connection in the first place. It doesn't help that the OP kept updating his question, incorporating my original answer into the query as well as his own attempts to create a connection.

Comment: @user1666620 Okay...my bad...or rather bad question asking etiquette on the OP's side. I'll restore the question properly...