# Is it possible to generate basic CRUD stored procedures on database with code-first entity framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, stored-procedures, crud

I have searched but couldnt find any useful thing about generating automatically basic CRUD stored procedures when creating the database in code first approach. I am wondering is there a way to do this simply or i should create all the CRUD stored procedure by old fashion?

Comment: That would slightly defeat the purpose of the ORM. Also, what would be the advantage of using SPs for CRUD operations?

Comment: Why would it defeat it? I think SPs are always beyond better than classic query execution because of no compilation needed and the results of executions with same parameters are cached. And also i dont want to write every crud operation with my hand.

Comment: Adhoc queries are only compiled once and The plan is reused just as with SPs. The same goes for parameters, so performance is hardly a motivation for CRUDs. Except for mass data processing or extremely long queries where the plan could take time to compile. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2734158/1373170

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed possible to use Migrations with a Code First Database to [generate stored procedures for CRUD operations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn468673) in Entity Framework 6 and beyond.  Note that this is not possible in this manner with Entity Framework 5 and earlier, though you could still use raw SQL calls.

1. Define your entity in the normal manner, and add a `DbSet` for the entity to your `DbContext` class.
2. Modify the `OnModelCreating` method of the `DbContext` to add the following entry: `modelBuilder.Entity<SomeEntity>().MapToStoredProcedures();`.
3. Using the Package Manager Console, generate a new migration with `add-migration`, i.e. `add-migration SPGenerate`.
4. Inspect the `Up` method of your migration to tweak the Stored Procedures to your liking.
5. Commit the migration to the database by issuing `update-database` in the Package Manager Console.

Comment: So you could use Sprocs, and  EF can be a handy even @ those places as well, good to know. Thnx