# Prepared Statement Inside Stored Procedure Called by PHP Prepared Statement

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement, sql-injection

I'm just wondering if this has any merit from a security standpoint. Say I have a PHP script that needs to get some stuff from the database. Is it safer all around to write it out in PHP and use a prepared statement that way, is it safer to encapsulate everything in a MySQL stored procedure, or can I actually get any security benefit from using a PHP prepared statement to call a MySQL stored procedure that has a prepared statement in it. Or does it not really matter as long as I user a prepared statement somewhere? Something like the following, but maybe a bit more complex:

PHP:

```
require 'path/to/login_utils.php';

try {
    $username = sanitize_validate_username($_POST['username']); // custom cleaning function from login_utils
    $pdo = connect_to_database(); // custom connection function from login_utils
    $select = "SELECT `password`
               FROM `tbl_login`
               WHERE `username`=:username;";
    $prepared = $pdo->prepare($select);
    $prepared->bindValue(":username", $username);
    $prepared->execute();
    $result = $prepared->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $prepared->closeCursor();
    if (isset($result) && count($result) > 0) {
        $password = $result['password'];
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die $e->getCode() . ': ' . $e->getMessage();
} finally {
    if (isset($pdo)) {
        unset($pdo);
    }
}
$userpass = $_POST['userpass'];
if (!isset($password) || !password_verify($userpass, $password)) {
    die 'Invalid username and password combo';
}
start_authenticated_session(); // custom session starting function from login_utils
echo 'You have been logged in';
exit;
```

But what if instead of dynamically making that SELECT in PHP, I put it behind a stored procedure with something like this?

MySQL:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_GetUserPassword(IN @username VARCHAR(255))
this_proc: BEGIN
    IF @username IS NULL
        THEN LEAVE this_proc;
    END IF;

    DECLARE @password VARCHAR(64);
    PREPARE get_password
    FROM 'SET @password = (
              SELECT `password`
              FROM `tbl_login`
              WHERE `username`=?
          );';
    EXECUTE get_password USING @username;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE get_password;
    SELECT @password;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

and then called it in my PHP script, replacing the first SELECT with this:

```
$select = "CALL usp_GetUserPassword(:username);";
```

or something like that, and I continued on to prepare and execute `$select` in PHP, even though the stored procedure has a prepared statement inside. Would that add any extra security?

Comment: Have a look at the url: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419604/mysql-stored-procedures-or-php-code

Comment: [Here](https://3v4l.org/jT1Gr) is your code fixed and all cargo cult stuff removed.

Answer (score 2):

Frankly, stored procedures offer no security that you can't get just as easily and effectively by using query parameters in your SQL which you prepare and execute directly from your application code.

And stored procedures are more difficult to develop in MySQL. There's no debugger, there's no package support, there's no standard library, the documentation is thin and difficult to read, there's no persistent compiler, etc.

In Microsoft/Oracle/IBM, stored procedures are more mature, and it is traditional to develop large packages of procedures for a project. But in MySQL, I almost never use stored procedures.

For SQL injection prevention, use query parameters. It's easier and just as effective.