# For Highly Optmized Select Query, Is it better to go with View or Stored Procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

For Highly Optmized Select Query, Is it better to go with View or Stored Procedure in SQL Server

Comment: Views are more useful because they can be used in queries.  No, wait, stored procedures are more useful because you can include other code.  Neither is "better".  They have different uses.

Comment: please look at [Stored Procedures Vs. Views](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773277/stored-procedures-vs-views) and [What is the difference between a stored procedure and a view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194995/what-is-the-difference-between-a-stored-procedure-and-a-view).

Comment: Definitely View for `SELECT` **without variable**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely View for `SELECT` **without variable**. If you need a criteria from variable, you can call a `view` inside `stored procedure`. Or maybe simply depends to what you need.