# call oracle view from asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

How can i call oracle 10g view from asp.net page?

View "DEPARTMENTS_VIEW" is

```
select Department_ID, DEPARTMEN_NAME , DISCOUNT    from DEPARTMENTS
```

c# code is

```
    OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = txtconnection.Text;
    conn.Open();
    OracleCommand objCmd = new OracleCommand();
    objCmd.Connection = conn;
    objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    objCmd.CommandText = "DEPARTMENTS_VIEW";
  
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    OracleDataAdapter oraDa = new OracleDataAdapter(objCmd);
    oraDa.Fill(ds, "department");
    gvGET_DEPARTMENTS.DataSource = ds.Tables["department"];
    gvGET_DEPARTMENTS.DataBind();
    conn.Close();
```

I'm getting this error code:

> ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
>
> PLS-00221: 'DEPARTMENTS_VIEW' is not a procedure or is undefined
>
> ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
>
> PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: Stored procedure and View are different things. You can't call a view like that. Read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194995/what-is-the-difference-between-a-stored-procedure-and-a-view and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773277/stored-procedures-vs-views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View is meant to be used the same way a table is used:

```
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = txtconnection.Text;
conn.Open();
OracleCommand objCmd = new OracleCommand();
objCmd.Connection = conn;
objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
objCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM DEPARTMENTS_VIEW";

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
OracleDataAdapter oraDa = new OracleDataAdapter(objCmd);
oraDa.Fill(ds, "department");
gvGET_DEPARTMENTS.DataSource = ds.Tables["department"];
gvGET_DEPARTMENTS.DataBind();
conn.Close();
```

You select data from a view the same way you select data from a table.

Comment: Thank you for your replay, what about Synonym , i allways get this error message 
PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement

Comment: @user2374513 - what synonym are you talking about?

Comment: @user2374513 Use of Synonyms depends on the type of object synonym is created. If it's a synonym  function you call it as a function, if it's a synonym table you select the data the same way you select data from a table.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have a enough reputation to comment on Dn24Z's answer but the answer should be:

```
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = txtconnection.Text;

conn.Open();
OracleCommand objCmd = new OracleCommand();
objCmd.Connection = conn;
objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
objCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM DEPARTMENTS_VIEW";

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
OracleDataAdapter oraDa = new OracleDataAdapter(objCmd);
oraDa.Fill(ds, "department");
gvGET_DEPARTMENTS.DataSource = ds.Tables["department"];
gvGET_DEPARTMENTS.DataBind();
conn.Close();
```

The key difference is that the objCmd.CommandType SHOULD BE objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;