# SQL Server Triggers, Stored Procedures

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers

I dont ever used triggers or stored procedures. Now i want to study how and when i use that.
I have table named Products, when products table filling with row i want to copy ProductID and UnitsInStock and paset into Inventory table. There is one problem in inventory table is column which must fill buy user when row is filling. Would triggers or stored procedures will be useful for this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i personally would never use triggers when i'm using code it is fine if all your work is being done in sql. The reason is that it is firstly difficult for someone else to realise that it is a trigger doing work in the back-end. Secoundly if there is an error in your code ... triggers are the last thing you check. And if column names change it is easy to pick up the error in code. Stored procedures are good, but it all depends from organisation to organisation. I have gotten into doing sql in code and like it as there is no back and forth work at looking through hundreds of stored procedures for the relevant one. My views though ...

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to copy stuff from one table to another after inserting or updating, a trigger is the right way to do this.

But if in your case a column must be filled with user-applied data, you probably will have to do this from your code.

About the use of stored procedures: take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15142/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-to-keeping-sql-in-stored-procs-versus-code). But there are many discussions on the web about this theme. Just google a bit around.

Answer (score 0):

Use a stored procedure, pass in all the values that are needed as parameters, then within a transaction post changes to the products table and then the inventory table and then commit your changes to both tables at once - so either both tables get updated, or neither does.