# Is separating MySQL code from PHP code a standard, common practice?

Tags: php, mysql

I've been told that it's a common practice to separate `MySQL` code from `PHP` code, is this true? Is this like a new coding standard? Are there any benefits of doing such?

Can someone direct me what are best coding practices (`PHP/MySQL`) when writing for masses (open source script for example).

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good question!

- *I've been told that it's a common practice to separate MySQL code from PHP code, is this true?*

  - absolutely true!
- *Is this like a new coding standard?*

  - and old old concept. there is no standard, but defacto exists
- *Are there any benefits of doing such?*

  - many benefits
  - benefits from de-coupling between Layers.
  - when business logic is de-coupled from Presentation logic, if requirement changes you can change it easily.
  - so not only separate sql from php, also separate HTML code from php logic

### using sqlMap

in the Java world there is MyBatis SqlMapper. This is very commonly used and this is what you want exactly if you are Java programmer.

But in PHP, hard to find something like MyBatis, the only thing I have found is `PRADO` http://www.pradosoft.com/

### using ORM

ORM = Object Relation Map. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping
This is also used. but i don't know there is ORM framework for PHP. if anyone knows, please let me know. **@jszobody has suggested** http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm.html (Thanks)

thanks.

Comment: "many benefits" doesn't tell what the benefits are. "benefits from de-coupling between layers" don't really answer the question, as they can be different layers, and you can still have PHP and SQL in the same file in dao layer. Other two of your points relate to presentation, not PHP and SQL. So what are the benefits?

Comment: @eis Thank you for your reply. As you already know, my English is not good. After reading your comment, I think I made two mistakes. first is choosing a word 'Layers' and second is insufficient examples.. To explain about benefit, I had tried some like this : "Let us think about separation PHP code and HTML, advantage is blah,, blah, for similar reason when SQL is separated from PHP code, blah blah". My answer getting longer, people understand less. So I had gave up. I hope see you my later answer.

Comment: @JungsuHeo *but i don't know there is ORM framework for PHP.* There are several, I'd highly recommend Doctrine. http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm.html

Answer (score 2):

> I've been told that it's a common practice to separate MySQL code from
>   PHP code, is this true?

I think, you are talking about [Loose coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling), Separating your application logic in parts (Building a good architecture), so you can keep things organized, maintainable. Actually, this is too broad discussion and I may not properly describe everything but to answer your question, **Yes**, it's a good (recommended) practice and a design principle in software development.

In an application, the most important part is the domain/business logic, which serves the application and this should be kept separate from other logics, such as presentation logic (`UI`). For example, if your application, deals with creating of users, products then you may keep them in a separate place each one as an entity of your application. For example

User management

```
class User {

    public function createUser()
    {
        // ...
    }

}
```

Product management

```
class Product {

    public function addProduct()
    {
        // ...
    }

}
```

This are your business logic and you may use/call these from a separate class/place like

```
$user = new User;
$user->create();
```

Now, think about the data storage mechanism, if you create a new user, you may need to put all the information in a place, it maybe a database, a flat file or ccould be an xml file, so, what should you do in your `createUser()` function, you should use a data access layer between your data storage and business logic, which means, whatever data storage you use, you should not use any code in your `createUser()` function (business logic) directly, instead you access the data storage via another layer ([DAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_layer)), for example, your `createUser()` function may look like something like this

```
class User {

    protected $storage = null;

    public function __construct($storage)
    {
       $this->storage = $storage;
    }

    public function createUser()
    {
        $userData = $_POST['first_name'];
        $userData = $_POST['user_name'];
        // more fields...

        // data validation

        $this->storage->save($userData);
    }
}
```

Now, to create a user and save it in a database, you can use it like

```
$storage = new DbStorage();
$user = new User($storage);
```

Maybe, you want to use a flat file to store data instead of a database, no problem, just change the data storage, i.e.

```
$storage = new FileStorage();
$user = new User($storage);
```

Now, see the difference, Your save method doesn't know about storage mechanism, it just calls `storage->save()` and each storage has it's own save mechanism, things are organized, clean and easy to maintain, change the storage mechanism without making any changes in your code. So, it's like

> Business Logic --> Data Access layer --> Data Storage

Here in data access layer, you should write code according to your storage mechanism, if you have a database as a storage then you write code according to that and in this case, your `DbStorage` may have it's own `abstract database layer` (different drivers for different Database, i.e. `mysql`, `oracle` etc), here `ORM` comes in action.

So, main thing is to keep things `loosely coupled`, which help you to build a clean and maintainable application. This is a little idea only. These links may help you

1. [Separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)
2. [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29)
3. [Software design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern)
4. [PHP - The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/)
5. [Data access layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_layer)
6. [ORM](http://www.slideshare.net/rob_knight/object-relational-mapping-in-php)

**Update :** I think I should add a bit about database abstraction layer's example

So, when you use a database for storage mechanism, you may use

```
$storage = new DbStorage();
$user = new User($storage);
```

But, this `DbStorage` should contain another layer for different types of databases, i.e. `myaql`, `oracle` etc. In this case, your `DbStorage` may look like this

```
class DbStorage{

    protected $db = null;

    public function __construct($database)
    {
        $this->db = $database;
    }

    public function save($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert($data);
    }

}
```

To use it, you may use code like this

```
$config = array('hostname' =>'localhost', 'username'=>'root', 'password'=>'123456', 'database'=>'myDatabase');
$storage = new DbStorage(new MySqlDriver($config));
$user = new User($storage);
```

Or for another database engine, you may use

```
$config = array('hostname', 'username', 'password');
$storage = new DbStorage(new OracleDriver($config));
$user = new User($storage);
```

Now, your different database drivers may look something like this

```
class MySqlDriver(){

    public $connection;
    public $database;
    public function __construct($config)
    {
        $this->connection = mysql_connect($config['hostname'], $config['username'], $config['password'], $config['database']);
        mysql_select_db($db);
    }

    public function insert($data)
    {
        // code for insert (mysql)
    }

}
```

For `oracle` you may have another class as `OracleDriver`

```
class OracleDriver(){

    // ...

    public function __construct($config)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public function insert($data)
    {
        // code for insert (oracle)
    }
}
```

This is just an idea of database abstraction layer and in most cases, configuration for each database (`MySqlDriver`, `OracleDriver`) may contain in configuration file, i.e. `database.php` and it my contains array like

```
return array(
    'mysql' => array(
        'hostname'=>'localhost',
        ...
    ),
        'oracle' => array(
        'hostname'=>'localhost',
        ...
    )
);
```

This is just a rough idea, you may find better examples online and there are lots of open source libraries to use in live projects.

Comment: @ProDraz don't take this one too literally too. There is *no* [usable] database abstraction layer in the world that will let you change storages from RDBMS to flat file that easy. A storage is too much tied to the other logic. For the simple dummy guestbook it will probably do.  But as soon as you'll decide to add users to it - it will fail deliberately.

Comment: @YourCommonSense, I just gave an idea and mentioned about `abstract database layer` in short but now I've updated with some examples, hope it make sense.

Comment: Two different RDBMSes is a much lively example than RDBMS and a flat file. But still it's just an imaginary feature, that raises thousands hardships to overcome when one is trying to implement it practice.

Comment: @YourCommonSense, Yes, you are right, this is an imaginary feature, won't it give an idea about the code organization, BTW, I don't use these (self implemented things), instead I use open source libraries and hope I didn't provide any working code here but an idea ?

Comment: That *is* the problem with ideas.

Comment: @SheikhHeera Wait, are you really recommending someone write their own entire abstraction layer and ORM, and then also suggesting that they use ext/mysql in this day and age?

Comment: @Charles, DID YOU REALLY READ THE FULL ANSWER because at the end I've mentioned `This is just a rough idea, you may find better examples online and there are lots of open source libraries to use in live projects` and how can I suggest someone to write their own `entire abstraction layer and ORM` even I don't use and I didn't mentioned about to use `mysql` extension anywhere but used dummy examples to illustrate the image. Anyways, thanks for the comment because most of the down voters don't leave a comment which makes me angry.

Comment: Creating instance of class must not be part of your model this must be handled by another layer or commonly by ORM. That path often delivers to much sufferings in the end : D

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this is standard across many programming languages. Typically you would write stored procedures and have your php code leverage those to do the database work. This separation makes it easier to manage your code base and helps with maintenance and extensability.

Comment: can you back up the claim that stored procedures is the typical way of doing this? Stored procedures tend to be very database-specific. I haven't seen MySQL stored procedures used a lot, so it's hard for me to believe that would be the *typical* way of doing things.

Comment: I'm not sure what proof would suffice to "back up my claim". There are many reasons for doing this approach. For one Stored Procedures are optimized on the database server which will help with performance. Beyond that there are advantages of having separation of sql and whatever language you're working with. It serves to have cleaner code which helps with maintenance and troubleshooting. I have seen and coded both ways, and hold the opinion that db code separation is overall a better method, which is proof enough for me. It's also embraced on many platforms, which should be an indicator.

Comment: even if it would be better, that's a different thing than claiming that it would be typical way of doing things. There are long discussions such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15142/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-to-keeping-sql-in-stored-procs-versus-code) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462978/when-should-you-use-stored-procedures) that don't agree on them being better. But that's beside the point if we think what is typical, what is the more common approach. I haven't seen anything suggesting that SPs would be the typical way people do this.

Comment: Fair enough.I suppose "Typically" could be taken in a subjective manner though. From my perspective I haven't personally seen anyone doing inline SQL in a while, so using stored procedures is the "Typical" way of doing things. You can certainly find people who prescribe to both philosophies as you have pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Don't take this advise too literally.
Because there is no way to follow it.

As you can see, noone provided you with *example* script. That's quite a problem with this site. Too much knowledge I'd call it. And lack of *practice*.

So, It cannot be used as a rule of thumb. Using stored procedures, where you can do single primary-key based lookup, is just an overkill. And ORM cannot create whatever complex query for you. So, it's rather *good intentions* than "coding standard".

Yet there *is* a rule of thumb you can easily follow: **never let your SQL and *HTML* to meet in a same file.** This one is quite easy to follow and way more *practical*, because you have to change appearance more often than database backends.