# Storing SQL code in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am thinking of storing non-sensitive SQL code in a column of a table. Is this considered an acceptable practice ? If yes, then  what would be the best datatype for this ? This code is to be accessed by C# code.

EDIT - I am using SQL server. But, this seems like a generic RDBMS question.

Also, related question - [What are the pros and cons to keeping SQL in Stored Procs versus Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15142/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-to-keeping-sql-in-stored-procs-versus-code)

Comment: 2) `NVARCHAR(MAX)`. What you try to accomplish ?

Comment: This is not acceptable practice. I'd urge you not to do this.

Comment: Are you using mysql or sql-server?

Comment: @BogdanSahlean - execute that SQL inside SSIS and then save the result set to a file.

Comment: @samyi: there are source control systems that use SQL Server to store the source code.

Comment: No, you wouldn't store any extraneous SQL data in another table be it query or creation script. If you need code to be accessed by another language, why not setup a stored routine, function, view, etc?

Comment: Yes but users do not access the database directly. Also, it's using the database as a "code/text" storage as it was designed to do... in other words, it's not intended for execution.  This is generally dangerous practice. IMO

Comment: I thought it would be a bit easier if someone else wants to change the SQL code later.

Comment: Please don't make assumptions about my opinions.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean - Wow ! I did not know that  source control systems use SQL Server to store the source code. Can you give me an example ? Also, then it seems that its okay to store my code in sql server. The length of the code might be only problem, because its limited by max variable size. Thanks.

Comment: You can design SSIS to be parameter and event driven so that you wouldn't have to do this except in most extreme cases. I think there are things you can do to avoid this.

Comment: @blasto At my firm, we use Git and Red Gate's SQL Source Control. Storing SQL in a DBMS is silly.

Comment: @blasto: Examples: [Team Foundation Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server), [Plastic SCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plastic_SCM)

Comment: @BogdanSahlean, I don't think this sort of architecture should be encouraged. Even a parameter driven proc with dynamic sql would be a better option than what OP is proposing.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO - Actually, I am not using it for source control.

Comment: @blasto: Please describe your *source problem*. Maybe some kind of parameterization could help you with SSIS.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean - I have to do joins, aggregate some data, add some "fake" columns (ie 'FixMe' as FAKE_COLUMN), convert an existing date - all in my select statement. and...filter by some criteria. All this is to generate a log file of sorts. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [stored procedures](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345415.aspx) for this.  They are basically what you describe, but with built-in support for maintenance and security.

You can create a procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetCustomerByID ( @CustomerID varchar(11) )
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT CustomerName, CustomerAddress
    FROM Customers
    WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID
END
```

Then [call it from C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#sectionToggle4) by using the `EXEC` command or by specifying `CommandType.StoredProcedure`.

```
SqlCommand sqc = new SqlCommand("GetCustomerByID", con);
sqc.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
sqc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", "FOOBAR");

var reader = sqc.ExecuteReader();
```

If you are calling it from SQL, use `EXEC`

```
EXEC GetCustomerByID @CustomerID = 'FOOBAR';
```

To change it later, use `ALTER PROCEDURE` or `DROP PROCEDURE` instead of `CREATE PROCEDURE`

Comment: Now I have a new challenge - My proc takes parameters, which VIEW cannot. so, I cannot use a view instead. I need to pivot the stored procedure as mentioned here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20960784/pivot-the-results-of-a-stored-procedure

Comment: @blasto - So use a table valued function instead.

Comment: @blasto If the stored procedure is being written for this purpose.. why not just return the pivoted result instead? In other words, do the pivot inside the sp