# Pivot the results of a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a stored procedure that always returns one row. I want to convert each column_name and its corresponding value to a row. Example -

```
ID | Name | Address
-----------------------
1  | Jim  | Home
```

should become -

```
ID      |  1
---------------------
Name    | Jim
Address | Home
```

How do I do this ?

Comment: Why do you need to pivot in SQL?  Pivoting in the app or report layer is typically much simpler.

Comment: @DStanley - I don't know how pivoting becomes simpler it the app/report layer. I could pivot it in C#, but I don't know how to do that yet.

Comment: Most reporting solutions allow for dynamic pivoting (adding columns dynamically based on row values). An example is the `Matrix` control in SSRS.  Many user control libraries have grids that can pivot dynamically.  SQL pivoting requires static column names (modulo using dynamic SQL) and the syntax is unintuitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to insert the values from the stored procedure into a (temporary) table, and then unpivot from there.  Psuedocode below:

```
CREATE TABLE #t (ID int, Name varchar(100), Address varchar(100))

INSERT INTO #t
EXEC stored_proc

SELECT ID = 'Name', [1] = Name
FROM #t
UNION ALL
SELECT ID = 'Address', [1] = Address
FROM #t

DROP TABLE #t
```