# how to Move data from one table to another c#

Tags: c#, oracle, .net-4.0, ado.net

I have a two table named `test1` and `test2` i want to move data from test1 to test2 in a way like if a condition matches update data else insert  in to database.I have successfully done the oracle query which i  posted down.I have to achieve two more tasks

**1>I have to move the operation in to console c# application

2>i have to remove the leading blank spaces for entries t2_fNAME and ACCOUNT_NUMBER**
How i can achieve this task do i need to do ado.net c# code if so how to do it

```
merge into test2 a
using test1 b
   on (a.t2_NAME = b.t1_NAME)
when matched then update
  set a.t2_fNAME = b.t1_fNAME,
      a.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = b.ACCOUNT_NO,

when not matched then
insert (t2_slno,t2_NAME,t2_fNAME,ACCOUNT_NUMBER)
values (t2_NODE_SEQ.NEXTVAL, b.t1_NAME,b.t1_fNAME,b.ACCOUNT_NO);
```

Comment: You can create a stored procedure using the above query and call that procedure from C# application.

Comment: How to remove leading blank space? or trim the entries

Comment: @Selva TS i will do as you said but how to remove the blank spaces from the beginning of t2_fNAME,ACCOUNT_NUMBER while inserting or updating

Comment: Use `TRIM` function in Oracle http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/trim.php

Comment: @Selva TS how to use trim while updating , i am getting error while doing like this set TRIM('  a.t2_fNAME  ')= b.t1_fNAME

Comment: I have posted answer. Its not tested, please modify the code according your requirement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75954/discussion-between-selva-ts-and-peter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can create a Console application and Use ADO.Net to execute the query
2. Use `Trim` Function in Oracle to remove leading blank spaces.

Here is the code (Not tested as I don't have Oracle DB)

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OracleClient;

namespace TestApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string connectionString = "Data Source=ThisOracleServer;Integrated Security=yes;";
            string queryString = @"merge into test2 a
                                    using test1 b
                                        on (a.t2_NAME = b.t1_NAME)
                                    when matched then update
                                        set a.t2_fNAME = TRIM(b.t1_fNAME),
                                            a.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = TRIM(b.ACCOUNT_NO),

                                    when not matched then
                                    insert (t2_slno,t2_NAME,t2_fNAME,ACCOUNT_NUMBER)
                                    values (t2_NODE_SEQ.NEXTVAL, b.t1_NAME,TRIM(b.t1_fNAME),TRIM(b.ACCOUNT_NO));";

            using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.CommandText = queryString;

                    try
                    {
                        connection.Open();
                        command.ExecuteScalar();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        //Log Exception here;
                        throw;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**References**

1. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw70f090(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. [Oracle TRIM Function](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/trim.php)

Comment: which is best selva , hard coding or creating stored procedure?

Comment: I prefer Stored Procedure, but there are lots of discussions in net SP Vs inline queries. Refer http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44544/stored-procedures-vs-inline-sql http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15142/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-to-keeping-sql-in-stored-procs-versus-code

Comment: Search in google  https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=inline%20query%20vs%20stored%20procedure

Comment: when i truncated table and used the above query, it is getting unique constraint violated exception ,how to prevent duplicates in above query.t2_slno is primary key here

Comment: What are your primary key and unique keys here? Use the PK and unique keys for your condition.

Comment: t2_slno is primary key here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75958/discussion-between-peter-and-selva-ts).