# How to execute INSERT..SELECT statement

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, ado.net, informix

I want to execute (`INSERT .. SELECT` ) statement like this :

```
cmdTxt.Clear();
cmdTxt.Append(" INSERT INTO  aast:sc1pen ");
cmdTxt.Append(" SELECT action_month,action_year,200,emp_num,penalty_action , ");
cmdTxt.Append("  'APPLY ' || penalty_reason || ' day ' , 0 , 0 ");
cmdTxt.Append(" FROM sc2pen WHERE sal_year = ? and sal_month = ? and penalty_type = 1 and pay_type = 0 ");
myIfxCmd.CommandText = cmdTxt.ToString();

myIfxCmd.Parameters.Clear();

myIfxCmd.Parameters.Add("sal_year", IfxType.Integer);
myIfxCmd.Parameters.Add("sal_month", IfxType.Integer);

myIfxCmd.Parameters[0].Value = penaltyDt.Rows[0]["sal_year"];
myIfxCmd.Parameters[1].Value = penaltyDt.Rows[0]["sal_month"];
```

---

Now I'm confused should i use

```
myIfxCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

To execute query like this although it include read operation ?

Comment: Yes,  use myIfxCmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); because you are not returning a result set to the client. The select is only being used to source the data to populate the insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it is not a good idea to do inline SQL as this does not make for maintainable code. This should be done in the database inside a stored procedure ideally - especially for inserting data into an existing table. Then you can execute the SP and return data inside an output parameter.

However, if you really want to go down this route then executing

```
    ExecuteNonQuery()
```

...will not return any data, only the records affected.
If you want to return some data, like the id of the newly inserted record, you want to use

```
    ExecuteScalar()
```

...which will allow a scalar value to be returned.

Comment: Your opening statement is purely opinion based. If you are going to make a statement like that you should back it up with valid reasons.  Many developers have legit reasons for keeping their SQL code inline.

Comment: FYI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15142/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-to-keeping-sql-in-stored-procs-versus-code

Comment: Yes it is my opinion @Fred. I suppose it depends on the scale of the project you are working on and the number of different database requests you make. I was simply saying that putting SQL in the database is a nicer, cleaner, more secure, more efficient, more maintainable, more reusable solution. Good arguments for and against inline SQL in your link but I would always side on putting a database query language where it belongs...in the database.

Comment: Stalkoverflow.com has only a one SP :)