# C# LINQ equivalent of a somewhat complex SQL query

Tags: linq-to-sql

So I have a SQL Query as Follows

```
SELECT P.Date, P.CategoryName, P.ProductName, SUM(Quantity) Quantity, SUM(Sales) TotalSales, IsLevelThree
FROM Products P LEFT JOIN LevelThreeTracking LTT
    ON P.Date = LTT.Date AND P.CategoryName = P.CategoryName AND P.SecurityID = LTT.SecurityID
WHERE P.Date = '12-31-2007' AND P.CategoryName= 'CategoryName'
GROUP BY P.Date, P.CategoryName, P.ProductName, LTT.IsLevelThree
HAVING SUM(Quantity) <> 0
ORDER BY P.ProductName
```

I'm Trying to Convert it to C# LINQ syntax and have the DataContext setup with the 2 tables.  I've tried a couple times at it (latest revision below) but the sql that gets generated looks monstrously complex and times out.  dtpBeginning is a DateTimePicker.

```
var results = from p in dbFAS.Products
group p by new {p.Date, p.CategoryName, p.ProductName}
into gp
join ltt in dbFAS.LevelThreeTracking on
new {gp.Key.Date, gp.Key.CategoryName, gp.Key.ProductName} equals
new {ltt.Date, ltt.CategoryName, ltt.ProductName} into everything
from e in everything.DefaultIfEmpty()
where gp.Key.Date == dtpBeginning.Value.Date && gp.Key.CategoryName == "CategoryName" && gp.Sum(p=>p.Quantity) != 0
select new
{
    gp.Key.Date,
    gp.Key.CategoryName,
    gp.Key.ProductName,
    Quantity = gp.Sum(hp=>hp.Quantity),
    TotalSales = gp.Sum(hp=>hp.Sales),
    e.Level3
};
```

Is there something simple I'm missing?  Any Ideas on how to refactor the LINQ statement to get something better?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Does it really need to be converted to LINQ?  I would suggest you put that query in a stored procedure because the equivalent LINQ query is painfully unreadable and unmaintainable.

Comment: That's totally doable (and my next step if no one comes up with anything), but I was wondering if my construction is flawed...

Comment: why did you get downvoted bro!!..some people are just too harsh

Comment: JPunyon - is there a compelling reason this _must_ be a LINQ query?  If not then please don't use LINQ for its own sake - in these cases it actually will hurt you in the long run (in terms of readability and maintainability)

Comment: There's no particular reason.  Upvote for the overall design sentiment ("The Right tool for the right Job").  But the point of the question is about learning where the boundaries of LINQ are and how refactoring might provide a better result.  (Of course I can write the SQL,I put it in the question)

Comment: LINQ is as easy to maintain as SQL code, if you know your LINQ as well as you know SQL. Nonetheless, there are many advantages to using LINQ,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530/linq-to-sql-vs-stored-procedures

Answer (score 9):

Try this query and let me know if it works. I changed the join into a where clause, this should eliminate all of the complex sub queries that LINQ generates when translating to SQL.

I'm not sure if I got the LEFT OUTER JOIN part right. I just included an OR condition that tests if one side exists.

```
from p in dbFAS.Products
from ltt in dbFAS.LevelThreeTracking
where p.CategoryName == "CategoryName"
    && (p.Date == ltt.Date || p.Date)
    && (p.CategoryName == ltt.CategoryName || p.CategoryName)
    && (p.ProductName == ltt.ProductName || p.ProductName)
    && p.Quantity > 0
group p by new {p.Date, p.CategoryName, p.ProductName, p.Quantity, p.Sales, ltt.Level3}
into gp
select new
{
    gp.Key.Date,
    gp.Key.CategoryName,
    gp.Key.ProductName,
    Quantity = gp.Sum(hp=>hp.Quantity),
    TotalSales = gp.Sum(hp=>hp.Sales),
    ltt.Level3
};
```

**EDIT:**
I thought about it some more, and this might be a little more clear and it could even compile! (The last one won't because of the || clauses)

```
from gp in
    (from p in dbFAS.Products
    join ltt in dbFAS.LevelThreeTracking on 
        new {p.Date, p.CategoryName, p.ProductName}
        equals new {ltt.Date, ltt.CategoryName, ltt.ProductName}
        into temp
    where p.CategoryName == "CategoryName"
        && p.Quantity > 0
    from t in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new
    {
        p.Date,
        p.CategoryName,
        p.ProductName,
        p.Quantity,
        p.Sales,
        t.Level3
    })
group gp by new {gp.Date, gp.CategoryName, gp.ProductName, gp.Level3}
select new
{
    gp.Key.Date,
    gp.Key.CategoryName,
    gp.Key.ProductName,
    Quantity = gp.Sum(hp=>hp.Quantity),
    TotalSales = gp.Sum(hp=>hp.Sales),
    gp.Level3
}
```