# If condition in LINQ Where clause

Tags: linq, conditional-statements, where-clause, c#-3.0, extension-methods

With Linq, can I use a conditional statement inside of a `Where` extension method?

Answer (score 66):

```
var query = someList.Where(a => (someCondition)? a == "something" : true);
```

so, if 'someCondition' is false, 'Where' will be skipped.

Comment: Analog (little shorter): 
`var query = someList.Where(a => !someCondition || a == "something");`

Answer (score 44):

Yes you can like:

```
var query = someList.Where(a => a == "something");
if (condition)
{
    query = query.Where(b => b == "something else");
}
var result = query.ToList();
```

Because `Where` is producing an `IQueryable`, the execution is deferred until the `ToList` in my example so you can chain `Where`s together as much as you want and then just execute it after you have passed all your conditions.

Comment: Where is not producing IQueryable, it is producing IEnumerable. Wrong answer

Comment: @OmerK Where does in-fact product IQueryable, if the object you are running the extension method on is also an IQueryable, if you run it on an IEnumerable, you will get an IEnumerable.

Comment: This is only viable if you don't need the element's value in the condition.

Answer (score 7):

Make use of `WhereIf` extenstion method avaialbe in linq

Example

```
if (SearchControlMain.PostingID.HasValue) 
    query = query.Where(q => q.PostingID == SearchControlMain.PostingID);
```

instead of above go for the below

```
query = query.WhereIf(SearchControlMain.CategoryID.HasValue, q => q.CategoryID == SearchControlMain.CategoryID);
```

[LINQ WhereIf Extension Method](http://blog.binaryocean.com/2008/03/07/LINQWhereIfExtensionMethod.aspx)

[LINQ to SQL Where Clause Optional Criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632434)

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is appropriate but it is quite useful, you can use ifs quite handily with conditional where clauses:

```
 var r = (from p in productinfo.tblproduct
                     where p.Accountid == accountid
                     select p);

            if (uuf1 != null)
                r = r.Where(p => p.UnitUserField1 == uuf1);

            if (uuf2!= null)
                r = r.Where(p => p.UnitUserField2 == uuf2);
```

So the where clause will be amended according to what is in UUF1 or UUF2 i.e. you might have only UUF1 with info, in which case it will take that and ignore the UUF2 where clause, you might have both in which it will take both or you might not have anything in UUF1 or 2 and your where clause will just take the accountid as the where clause.

Answer (score 3):

In my case there were two "conditional" where depending on search keys, so I did:

```
    var query = db.Package.Include("SomeThing")
    .Where(item => searchString1 == null || searchString1 == "" || item.Contains(searchString1))
    .Where(item => searchString2 == null || searchString2 == "" || item.Contains(searchString2));
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

```
from item in items
where condition1
&& (condition2 ? true : condition3)
select item
```

This is how can you can do it with the noob Linq syntax.
This applies the condition3 only if condition2 is false.
If condition2 is true, you are essentially doing `&& true` which has no effect on the where clause.

So it is essentially doing this:

```
if(condition2)
{
    from item in items
    where condition1
    select item
else
{
    from item in items
    where condition1
    && condition3
    select item
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a scenario like this where I had to check for null within the list itself. This is what I did.

```
items = from p in items
        where p.property1 != null   //Add other if conditions
        select p;

// Use items the way you would use inside the if condition
```

But as Kelsey pointed out this would work too -

```
items = items.Where(a => a.property1 != null);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the question is, but a possible answer could be:

Yes,

```
list.Where(item => { if (Foo(item)) return true; else return false; });
```

It would be a complicated way of saying something simple, though.

Comment: Which is equal to: list.Where(item => Foo(item));

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I wanted to keep the elements which met my criteria and log the ones that didn't without iterating multiple times.

```cs
var merchantsWithLocations = allMerchants.Where(m =>
    {
        if (m.Locations?.Any() != true)
        {
            _logger.Log("Merchant {merchantId} has no locations", m.Id);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    };
```

Any time you want to do a side-effect per element (such as logging), breaking out the lambda into a statement body makes it easy to reason about.