# C# Linq Query on database using field name as a variable

Tags: c#, database, linq, variables

Here is my code. Can anyone help me refactor this piece of code. i'm trying to use field name as variable so I wouldn't have to use switch case. Something like from `dr in db.Users where dr.FieldName.Contains(value)`.

```
public static List<User> GetUser(string value, string fieldName)
{
    var db = new CCPTDataContext();
    var users = new List<User>();

    switch (fieldName)
    {
        case "FirstName":
            users = (from dr in db.Users where dr.FirstName.Contains(value)
                     select new User
                     {
                         Username = dr.Username,
                         FirstName = dr.FirstName,
                         LastName = dr.LastName
                     }).ToList();

            break;
        case "LastName":
            users = (from dr in db.Users where dr.LastName.Contains(value)
                     select new User
                     {
                         Username = dr.Username,
                         FirstName = dr.FirstName,
                         LastName = dr.LastName
                     }).ToList();
            break;
    }
    return users;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682835/if-condition-in-linq-where-clause)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create the Expression Tree manually using classes from `System.Linq.Expression` namespace:

```
public static Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> GetPropertyContainsValueExpression<TSource>(string propertyName, string value)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "x");
    var prop = Expression.Property(param, propertyName);
    var valueExp = Expression.Constant(value, typeof(string));
    var contains = Expression.Call(prop, "Contains", null, valueExp);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(contains, param);
}
```

then you can use it like that:

```
public static List<User> GetUser(string value, string fieldName)
{
    var db = new CCPTDataContext();

    return db.Users.Where(GetPropertyContainsValueExpression<User>(fieldName, value)).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Some providers (I think EF 5) might not correctly parameterize the query in the above snippet. In order to get the parameterized queries, what I do is wrap the value in a `Tuple` and get the `Item1` property:

`var container = new Tuple<string>(value); var containerExpression = Expression.Constant(container, typeof(Tuple<string>)); var valueExp = Expression.Property(containerExpression, "Item1");`

Comment: @Kosar you're welcome! You should consider marking the answer as accepted if it solved your problem. That's how SO works!

Comment: @Marcin, I tried to mark as accepted, couldn't find any link, button or something like that for it. Can you guide me how to do that.

Comment: @Kosar Right below post score the should be gray mark you can click. Here is a great question about that: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
users = (from dr in db.Users 
where (fieldName.Equals("FirstName") && dr.FirstName.Contains(value))
      || (fieldName.Equals("LastName") && dr.LastName.Contains(value))
                 select new User
                 {
                     Username = dr.Username,
                     FirstName = dr.FirstName,
                     LastName = dr.LastName
                 }).ToList();
```