# linq - include where parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a strange question about Linq.

I have this query:

```
 var results = (from p in hotsheetDB.Properties
                           where p.PCode == pCode
                           && p.PropertyStatusID == propertyStatuses
                           orderby p.PropertyID descending
                           select new
                           {
                               PropertyId = p.PropertyID,
                               PCode = p.PCode,
                               PropertyTypeName = p.cfgPropertyType.Name,
                               FullAddress = p.Address1 + " " + p.Address2,
                               ZipCode = p.ZipCode.Code,
                               CityName = p.cfgCity.Name,
                               LivingSquareFeet = p.LivingSquareFeet,
                               LotSquareFeet = p.LotSquareFeet,
                               NumBedrooms = p.NumBedrooms,
                               NumBathrooms = p.NumBathrooms,
                               PropertyStatusName = p.cfgPropertyStatuse.Name
                           });
```

You notice pCode and propertyStatuses parameters. They are input values from the users. He wants to search by pCode or/and by propertyStatuses.

So, when the user fills in **only pCode** he wants to return all the records with that pCode having ANY propertyStatuses...well, because propertyStatuses IS in the query but it's null, **the query will not return anything** (because there is no record with empty(null) propertyStatuses...

Therefore, the question: *is there any way to include these where params only whey they have values?* (without making separate N queries with all the combination? (I have multiple inputs)

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I don't get why people no longer do this stuff on the database side? Why is everyone using linq to do stuff like this?  Not in my shop baby..could've been `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE (MyID = @ID OR @ID IS NULL)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ to SQL Where Clause Optional Criteria](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/632434/linq-to-sql-where-clause-optional-criteria)

Comment: @JonH: not sure if you're trolling or actually serious :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your `where` clause to make the parts which include `null` always return true.

For example:

```
where (pCode == null || p.PCode == pCode)
   && (propertyStatuses == null || p.PropertyStatusID == propertyStatuses)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm only guessing here but try:

```
where p.PCode == pCode && 
(p.PropertyStatusID == null || p.PropertyStatusID == propertyStatuses)
```