# Smarter where clause?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I've been experimenting with LINQ to SQL recently and have a quick question. 
The basic premise is I have a search request which contains a Make and Model which I use to search a DB containing cars.

The expression for my Where Clause is shown below:

```
.Where(c => c.make == search.make  && c.model == search.model)
```

This is fine when my search contains both a make and a model. The problem arises when it only contains a make(or vice versa) and not both search fields. I want it to return all cars of that make, it is however returning none.

Im assuming this is because it is looking for the make plus a model that is null or empty?

Is there an elegant way to get around this other than manually building up the query with a series of "if not null append to query" type steps?

Comment: That would interest me too, now i solved this kind of problem with an If Else and then in the both cases i execute a different Linq to Sql query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could write something like this:

```
.Where(c => c.make == search.make ?? c.make && c.model == search.model ?? c.model)
```

Comment: Thanks Paulo, can you explain what's happening here? I'm quite new to LINQ and LAMBDA stuff, haven't seen the "??" syntax used before?

Comment: The `??` is the coalesce operator. If the value on the left side is null it will use the value on the right side. It's equivalent to `(x == null ? y : x)`

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried:

```
.Where(c => (search.make == null || c.make == search.make)  && (search.model == null || c.model == search.model))
```

Update: There's actually a nice treatment of the general problem, and clean solutions, here:
[LINQ to SQL Where Clause Optional Criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632434/linq-to-sql-where-clause-optional-criteria). The consensus seems to be that an extension method is cleanest.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. I knew there would be a better way, just didnt jump out at me...it's been a long week :)

Answer (score 2):

```
.Where(c => (search.make == null || c.make == search.make) && 
            (search.model == null || c.model == search.model))
```

Comment: isn't this doing the wrong thing? (getting cars whose model is null, even if the search was for a specific make and model?)

Comment: Thanks @Tao, I misunderstood the question. Corrected my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Boob: If it works, give Tao the credit, he got it right in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, split it:

```
IQueryable<Car> query = ...
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search.make))
    query = query.Where(c => c.make == search.make);
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search.model))
    query = query.Where(c => c.model== search.model);
```

This produces the most appropriate TSQL, in that it won't include redundant `WHERE` clauses or additional parameters, allowing the RDBMS to optimise (separately) the "make", "model" and "make and model" queries.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
.Where(c => 
    (search.make == null || c.make == search.make) &&
    (search.model == null || c.model == search.model))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.Where(c => (string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.make) || c.make == search.make) && 
            (string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.model) || c.model == search.model))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.Where(c => (string.IsNullOrEmpty(search.make) || c.make == search.make) &&
            (string.IsNullOrEmpty(search.model) || c.model == search.model))
```

That's assuming the properties are strings.

Comment: Actually, on re-reading the question it's probably not even necessary to call IsNullOrEmpty. Depends how you're creating your search object.

Answer (score 0):

```
Where(c => (search.make == null || c.make == search.make) && 
           (search.model == null || c.model == search.model))
```