# Linq to Entities IncludeIf Extension

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

In my repositories, I find that the WhereIf Linq-to-sql extension from this thread ([LINQ to SQL Where Clause Optional Criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632434/linq-to-sql-where-clause-optional-criteria)) is very useful -- especially the IEnumerable version.

I would like to do the same thing with the Include() statement, but I'm not very good with writing extensions. I got stuck on the declaration of the extension.

Can anyone help me port the WhereIf extension to IncludeIf?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two `Include(...)`, one that is already an extension method to `IQueryable<T>` and one that is a method of `DbQuery<T>`. This should give you both extensions `IncludeIf<>`

```
public static class QueryableEx
{
    public static IQueryable<T> IncludeIf<T, TProperty>(this IQueryable<T> source, bool condition, Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> path) where T : class
    {
        if (condition)
        {
            return source.Include(path);
        }
        else
        {
            return source;
        }
    }

    public static DbQuery<TResult> IncludeIf<TResult>(this DbQuery<TResult> query, bool condition, string path)
    {
        if (condition)
        {
            return query.Include(path);
        }
        else
        {
            return query;
        }            
    }
}
```

Remember that you need to put them in a static class like I have done.