# ASP.NET Entity Framework: LINQ2SQL or Stored Procedures?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I'm wondering about if there is a difference (in performance) when I use:

```
User usr = (from u in Adapter.User
            where u.Login == login
            select u).FirstOrDefault();
```

or

```
 User usr = Adapter.getUserByLogin(login); //stored procedure
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be the same topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752064/performance-difference-between-linq-and-stored-procedures) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530/linq-to-sql-vs-stored-procedures).