# Stored procedures vs Linq2Entities

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, linq-to-entities, methodology

I have recently moved into a team leader position in a company that has some very old school developers. I'm trying so hard to convince them to use LINQ2Entities and over using tools like Codesmith to generate stored procedures and DAL layers. It appears that I'm not getting through. Does anyone know of any ways to prove my point?

Comment: Does this belong more on programmers se?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post might help you:

[LINQ-to-SQL vs stored procedures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530/linq-to-sql-vs-stored-procedures)

[Performance Difference between LINQ and Stored Procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752064/performance-difference-between-linq-and-stored-procedures)

your question might be posted here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Regards