# Linq vs. stored procedures

Tags: .net, sql, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LINQ-to-SQL vs stored procedures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530/linq-to-sql-vs-stored-procedures)

Does any body know that advantage of writing LINQ code in a .NET application over using stored procedures. Also are there any new and upcoming languages that may make more sense to devote time towards learning?

Comment: When you say new languages, what are you asking about? New ORM's? Are you considering linq a language? As far as ORM's are concerned, MS is devoting its time to Entity Framework so if I was you I would do the same

Comment: This looks like two separate questions and the second one (about languages that make more sense to which to devote time) is too vague.