# LINQ or stored procedure? Which one is advantageous?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures, c#-3.0

I am using C# in Visual Studio 2008. I have an aspx page which binds a list view. The data is accessed from 8 tables.

Which one should I prefer for maximum performance, a stored procedure or linq in the code behind?

Which one is having the minimum network traffic?

Comment: It's hard to tell in general, without seeing your LINQ queries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530/linq-to-sql-vs-stored-procedures

Answer (score 2):

Stored procedures are almost always faster and allow more control of query execution, but the development time to build them may not be justified on lower traffic projects or projects with very short development schedules.

Comment: +1, this sums it up pretty concisely and is exactly right.

Comment: @E.J.Brennan: Not taking any company standards and patterns into account but purely on a base level, if you already have the data for the tables returned in your application and the tables only ever have a few hundred records, writing another SPROC on top of it to combine the tables you already have returned in your app instead of using LINQ would in my oppinion be unnecessary overhead.

Comment: A well crafted, properly parametrized query is typically just as fast as any stored procedure. Speed isn't the main advantage for stored procedures - it's more about security (not having to give database users direct table access to select data)

Answer (score 2):

It is situational in most cases and also depends on the size of the data.
Also first and foremost, always check what your teams current coding standards and patterns are. If standards in your company say use SPROCS always, than adhere to those standards.

**Lots of Records (SPROC)**
If the expected data in the tables could possibly be a few hundred thousand records each it might be complete overhead to have a million records in total for 8 tables returned only to retrieve a small subset of data with LINQ.

LINQ will keep the records it currently iterates through in memory until the expected result set is build. This will most likely end up with all the million records in memory + the records for the result set in memory.

Also note that Visual Studio has a limit of 2GB memory (regardless of how much RAM you got) than it falls on it's face (during debug mode on a 32bit system, not sure about 64bit). I did in the past have issues with querying large data sets with LINQ whereby I run into out of memory exceptions.

A SPROC maybe faster and safer in that case.

**Few Records (LINQ)**
If on the other hand the data in each of the 8 tables will always be rather small not changing much in the future, than using LINQ will make little difference. However, do test if multiple table joins might be slower in LINQ than in a SPROC.

**Edit (Compare/Analyse Execution Plans)**
Also note that the SQL produced for joins using LINQ is very efficient in .NET 4.0 in most cases, not sure about .NET 3/3.5 but using SQL profiler you can see the generate SQL and run it in SQL comparing it to a SPROC execution plan.