# Security and speed of linq with stored procedure

Tags: linq, security, stored-procedures

I want to use linq with stored procedure in asp.net,
but if it reduces security of information, I prefer using linq without stored procedure.
Is there any source to guide me about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any security risk of using linq with stored procs would be the same as using stored procs directly with the old school Db/SqlCommand approach.  I would suggest you see  [LINQ-to-SQL vs stored procedures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530/linq-to-sql-vs-stored-procedures) the accepted answer gives a pretty good detail of the advantage each have over the other.